# Using Span for Triggering Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have several icons in the header that is used from a font and wrapped with

```
<li style="margin-top: 15px">
    <span class="myIcons" id="messages" style="font-size: 5px">m</span>
</li>
```

I want to use it to trigger bootstrap dropdown however in its documentation, it uses button and div and, I couldn't figure out how to trigger it when clicked on the font.

Should I try using jquery and try to trigger the dropdown to open on click on `#messages`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use `<button>`'s and `<div>`'s - the important thing is to have a `data-toggle="dropdown"` on the triggering element :

```html
<ul class="dropdown">  

  <!-- your markup -->  
  <li style="margin-top: 15px" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="myIcons" id="messages" style="font-size:5px">m</span>
  </li>
  <!--// your markup -->      

  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7ujpzs58/**